# Need software to store an image as text (not about OCR)

Tags: image, text, converters

I need a way to convert an image into a text file, with copyable, pasteable text. Image data is after all just zeroes and ones, so this should not be impossible, but i have failed in finding software to do this online (Closest i got was something that converted mp3s to a string of hexadecimals, but the download page no longer existed and the whole page seemed out of the good old times of windows 98). So, does anyone know a programme that can turn a .jpg file into a .txt file? (and not just by changing the file name extension of course, actually making a picture into text and being able to bring it back later.)

Thanks in advance!

//LJ

Comment: Are you looking for something like [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An image contains a lot of data, you could Base64 encode the image using something like PHP but it's going to be a LONG string!

I've just put this together for you for files < 2MB

http://bigpebbles.co.uk/base64-file-converter